# Questions about hardware/software for optical media extraction to broad?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

It was suggested on [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272395/306877) to ask in HR meta if this is the place for this type of question.

I have several hundreds of optical media disks (mainly DVD-R & CD-R) that stores data, that needs to be transferred to a hard disk drive to improve accessibility.

I need to ask a question about how to make a strategy (software/hardware system) to optimise the time used to perform extraction of this data from all of the disks.

Would the following question be on topic for this community?

> I need a good strategy for extracting data from several hundreds of optical media disks to a filesystem.
>
> The process of extracting should be as easy as inserting the media into a drive, get extracted, then automatically ejected when finished. Alternatively, inserting several media disks into a media carrousel, inserted the carrousel into the "drive", and give feedback when it is finished extracting all of the disks, either by playing a sound or sending an e-mail.
>
> Are there any solutions already available, and if not; What hardware and what software / operating system would I need?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually difficult to judge.

From what I can tell, you need a combined hardware and software solution. This community recommends hardware solutions only, which may not be ideal.

You could try to reword your question to ask for a hardware solution that has a cd drive and an output hard drive, which has reprogrammable firmware. Then you could ask SR for the software to put on it.

Maybe.

Comment: I see a few questions here going on different sites. I guess I should start asking if there are any carousel DVD readers at all, the performance of such a device and the cost. The result of that could be used to make a question that compares this to the performance and cost of using ~4-8 slot-in DVD readers on a USB hub, or similar. Would that be on-topic here? Then, if I find one or more hardware-solutions, I could continue asking questions about software solutions in SR.

Comment: The performance comparison isn't on-topic, @JoachimBratteli, but the carousel dvd reader likely is if you can specify your requirements in enough detail.

Comment: I will give it a try. Would this be ok? "I have several hundreds of optical media disks (mainly DVD-R & CD-R) that stores data, that needs to be transferred to a hard disk drive to improve accessibility. As a possible alternative to a bunch of external slot-in DVDs connected to a controller I'm looking for a CD/DVD-R reader carousel that could be connected and controlled from a computer to read data on the DVDs. Does such a device exist?"

Comment: @JoachimBratteli That would be on-topic, however you'd need to specify as many requirements as possible. Something like the number of slots you need in each carousel, an auto-eject function, etc.